# Conflicting types with double in a function definition

Tags: c

I get an error "conflicting types for 'abs' in my function.
The code is very simple.

```
double abs (double x) {  // Returns absolute value
if (x<0)
    return (x*(-1));
else
    return x;
}
```

This is on a C proyect on codeblocks.
I already tried casting the returns but the error remains anyway.

Comment: BTW: This `abs(-0.0)` returns `-0.0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you have `<stdlib.h>` included because `abs` is already declared there and has the signature `int abs(int)`, so your definition produces "conflicting types".

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in your code per se.  Rather, there is another function already defined named `abs()` with a different prototype - probably operating on integers.  Unlike C++, C doesn't permit function overloading.

I suggest using `fabs()` from `math.h` instead.  Not only is it already there, but it will typically compile to a single FPU instruction instead of a call and conditional branch.

There is also `fabsf()` and `fabsl()` for performing the same operation on `float` and `long double` respectively.  To use these, you might need to select C99 or C11 mode, as these functions weren't specified in the original ANSI standard.